# SQL query to retrieve all the records that have not indicated category

Tags: posts, sql

I need to get the ID posts for which the category(taxonomy "category") is not specified.
Post include other taxonomy.

I get posts from code:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT ...', , ARRAY_A);
```

My query selects the desired type of recording

```
SELECT distinct posts.ID FROM wp_posts AS posts 

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS cat_link ON
cat_link.object_id = posts.ID 

LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS cat_tax ON
cat_link.term_taxonomy_id = cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id AND cat_tax.taxonomy NOT IN ('category') 

WHERE post_type = 'popular_music' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY posts.ID DESC
```

But it is not considered:

```
cat_link.term_taxonomy_id = cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id AND cat_tax.taxonomy NOT IN ('category')
```

How to select the record, Uncategorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're looking for the SQL for the equivalent of

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'popular_music',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array (
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    ) ;
$query = new WP_Query ($args) ;
echo $query->request ;
```

If so, then this is the SQL that WP_Query produces

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $wpdb->posts.ID
FROM
    $wpdb->posts
WHERE
    1=1 AND
    ( 
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM
                $wpdb->term_relationships INNER JOIN
                $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE
                $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND
                $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
        )
    ) AND
    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'popular_music' AND
    (($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID DESC
```

Comment: How did you get SQL from WP_Query?

Comment: I edited my answer to to add the `echo $query->request ; ` statement I used to get the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you're after is something similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts AS posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        AS cat_link
        ON cat_link.object_id = posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
        AS cat_tax
        ON cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id = cat_link.term_taxonomy_id
        AND cat_tax.taxonomy = 'category'
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND cat_link.object_id IS NULL
```

Comment: `AND cat.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (12,46,33)` - Not suitable as the category a lot and they are constantly being added `AND cat.object_id IS NULL";` - return zero results

Comment: AND cat.object_id IS NULL"; - return zero results, because it belongs to another post taxonomy

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, have you tried the `AND cat.object_id IS NULL` query without the other 2 `WHERE` conditions, or at the very least, with the `post_type` clause set to your custom post type (eg `WHERE post_type = 'product'` or `WHERE post_type = 'staff'`?

Comment: I tried to use each option separately

Comment: Try eliminating all unnecessary conditions from the `WHERE` clause, then. eg `SELECT posts.* FROM wp_posts AS posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS cat ON cat.object_id = posts.ID WHERE AND cat.object_id IS NULL` That should prove the SQL works; then all you have to do is add in a condition that narrows to the custom post type you're after.

Comment: You may not understand the question a little bit. I need something similar this `$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy != 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` taking into account your code

Comment: Gotcha - I've amended the answer. Let me know if I've hit the mark

Comment: I edited the question, your code has not helped. cat_link.object_id - exist, by custom tax

Comment: Then change `'category'` to your custom taxonomy, and `'post'` to your custom post type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53912/discussion-between-trubine-and-psd-to-final).

Comment: Recording may belong to both categories and a taxonomy. I need post Uncategorised